# equallogic as direct network drive

Tags: storage, network-share, network-attached-storage, dell-equallogic

at work we have an equallogic which currently does nothing. I know how to create volumes and configure the equallogic.

But I am wondering if it is possible to use it as a direct network drive via iSCSI with. The main problem I see is the filesystem. I would need to use a locking filesystem. Does anyone have a good idea which software to use?

Comment: What do you intend to connect the storage to?

Comment: a network. Which then would allow multiple clients to acces it via iSCSI

Comment: And that's not possible already? What are your clients?

Comment: "Network drive" sounds like you're after a network share, but "direct" and "iSCSI" sound more like you're after block-level access. Go in the direction of ewwhite's answer if a network share is what you're after. If you're looking for block level access, what operating systems will your hosts have? And what application is it for? (Database, Virtualization, Etc)

Answer (score 4):

I *think* you're asking for a way to turn your Dell Equallogic storage into shared network storage; e.g. converting SAN to NAS.

The Equallogic SAN is block-only, so your easiest solution is to configure a server to interface with the Equallogic device over iSCSI. Use that server to present the block storage to the rest of your network as a network filesystem.

You don't mention the operating systems in use, but with a Windows server, you could easily provide Samba/CIFS to your clients. If a Linux machine, export NFS or Samba/CIFS shares.